# how to show properties of a featureCollection in d3 (using the mouse)

Tags: d3.js

After displaying my map with D3, I need to place customer locations on it. No problems doing that but when the user clicks on on of my customer locations I need to display data about the location that is currently held in the properties member. Right now, when I console.log() the selected customer location, I get the entire features data and not the single feature data that the user selected. Here is my customer location data:

```
var customerListData =
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
    {
        "geometry":{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-77.4918710, 38.1991360]},
        "properties": {"NUM":0,"NAME":"DFA54635","formattedAddress":"4503 Cornwall     Court, Fredericksburg, VA 22408, USA"}
    },
    {
        "geometry":{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-81.0974798, 36.9448153]},
        "properties": {"NUM":1,"NAME":"DFA54644","formattedAddress":"475 North 22nd Street, Wytheville, VA 24382, USA"}
    }
   ...
```

and here is how I am displaying this data

```
// paint the customer locations
svg.selectAll(".cities").data([customerListData])
    .enter().append("path")
.attr("class","cities")
.attr("d", path)
.on("click", function(d) 
     {
   console.log(d);
     }) 
.append("title").text(function(d) 
{ 
    console.log(d);
});
```

The console log in both cases above displays the entire feature collection:

```
Object { type="FeatureCollection", features=[105]}
```

So...How can I get the exact feature using the mouse as input?

Comment: Have you tried `.data(customerListData.features)`?

Comment: Yes. If I attempt to display my data using (svg.selectAll(".cities").data(customerListData.features)) then nothing gets displayed. However the console.log() is called many times and shows this:  Object { geometry={...}, properties={...}}

Comment: do I need to display my data one point at a time and not the entire collection at once? Seems like this may work, but it also seems to be slow process.

Comment: Yes, you would need to draw one at a time. This won't slow the drawing down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is presumably a geo.path defined with your projection. If you want to show each individual point and access the data bound to each point, then you'll need to append them not using geo.path but by placing them individually and individually accessing the projection:

```
 d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle.cities").data(customerListData.features)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("r", 5)
 .attr("cx", function(d) {return projection([d.geometry.coordinates])[0]})
 .attr("cy", function(d) {return projection([d.geometry.coordinates])[1]})
 .on("click", function(d) {console.log(d)})
```

This is assuming your projection variable is named "projection". It is a function that accepts a two-value array and returns a two-value projected array, the first value [0] is the x coordinate and the second value [1] is the y coordinate.

There may be a way to access each point using geo.path but not that I'm aware.

Comment: I didn't actually solve my problem with the code above but it (the code above) is close enough to my solution that this is the correct way to go here. As always, thanks for the help.